# MVCContrib Grid custom design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I would like to reproduce the following design

```
+-----------------------------------+---+---+
| some text here                    | A | B |
+-----------------------------------+---+---+
| some multiline text here                  |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Where A and B are fixed width columns containing images.

This would be easily accomplished using a `<table>` element like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some text here</td>
        <td width="20"><img alt="" src="/imageurl" /></td>
        <td width="20"><img alt="" src="/imageurl" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3">some multiline text here</td></tr>
</table>
```

But I am using the Grid helper within the MVCContrib project. Is there a way to obtain a design like this one for every item inside a list of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own GridRenderer.
From Jeremy Skinner's [blog](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/23/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-3-gridmodels-and-gridrenderers/):

> The default GridRenderer is the
>   HtmlTableGridRenderer. Which,
>   surprisingly enough, renders the grid
>   as an HTML table. By specifying your
>   own GridRenderer, you can completely
>   alter how the grid is rendered without
>   resorting to completely rewriting the
>   grid component.

You can get some ideas from HtmlTableGridRenderer's [source code](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6aa25407de83#src%2fMVCContrib%2fUI%2fGrid%2fHtmlTableGridRenderer.cs).